# Postgres Window Function including most recent row that doesn't match window criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql

The code:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (SELECT *
        , high > max(high) OVER (PARTITION BY ticker ORDER BY _1h DESC ROWS BETWEEN 12 PRECEDING AND 9 FOLLOWING EXCLUDE CURRENT ROW) AS pivot_low,
          low < min(low) OVER (PARTITION BY ticker ORDER BY _1h DESC ROWS BETWEEN 12 PRECEDING AND 9 FOLLOWING EXCLUDE CURRENT ROW) AS pivot_high,
          '1h' AS timeframe

    FROM _1_hour
    ORDER BY _1h DESC
    ) sub

WHERE pivot_high or pivot_low
ORDER BY ticker, _1h DESC;
```

Example of _1h table content:

| ticker | _1h | open | high | low | close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-16 18:00:00+00 | 1.22147 | 1.2217 | 1.22102 | 1.2213 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-16 17:00:00+00 | 1.21998 | 1.22153 | 1.21987 | 1.22146 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-16 16:00:00+00 | 1.21967 | 1.22051 | 1.21906 | 1.21999 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-16 15:00:00+00 | 1.21889 | 1.21998 | 1.21875 | 1.21965 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-16 14:00:00+00 | 1.2161 | 1.21934 | 1.21536 | 1.2189 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-16 13:00:00+00 | 1.21764 | 1.21828 | 1.21588 | 1.2161 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-16 12:00:00+00 | 1.21789 | 1.21845 | 1.21656 | 1.21763 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-16 11:00:00+00 | 1.21517 | 1.21808 | 1.21467 | 1.21788 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-16 10:00:00+00 | 1.21463 | 1.2157 | 1.21428 | 1.21517 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-16 09:00:00+00 | 1.21598 | 1.21666 | 1.21458 | 1.21465 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-16 08:00:00+00 | 1.2175 | 1.21769 | 1.21519 | 1.21596 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-16 07:00:00+00 | 1.21692 | 1.21781 | 1.21624 | 1.21754 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-16 06:00:00+00 | 1.2166 | 1.2172 | 1.2163 | 1.2169 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-16 05:00:00+00 | 1.21602 | 1.2166 | 1.21577 | 1.21659 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-16 04:00:00+00 | 1.2156 | 1.21619 | 1.21548 | 1.21602 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-16 03:00:00+00 | 1.21564 | 1.21573 | 1.21503 | 1.21561 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-16 02:00:00+00 | 1.21533 | 1.21591 | 1.2151 | 1.21563 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-16 01:00:00+00 | 1.2147 | 1.21563 | 1.21469 | 1.21532 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-16 00:00:00+00 | 1.21549 | 1.21574 | 1.21451 | 1.21469 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-15 23:00:00+00 | 1.21502 | 1.21549 | 1.21481 | 1.21547 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-15 22:00:00+00 | 1.21469 | 1.21575 | 1.21443 | 1.21502 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-15 21:00:00+00 | 1.21409 | 1.21554 | 1.21368 | 1.2147 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-13 20:00:00+00 | 1.21405 | 1.2146 | 1.21338 | 1.21442 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-13 19:00:00+00 | 1.21356 | 1.21418 | 1.21348 | 1.21404 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-13 18:00:00+00 | 1.21325 | 1.21419 | 1.21314 | 1.21355 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-13 17:00:00+00 | 1.2137 | 1.21376 | 1.21225 | 1.21326 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-13 16:00:00+00 | 1.21367 | 1.21466 | 1.21342 | 1.21369 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-13 15:00:00+00 | 1.21406 | 1.21438 | 1.21315 | 1.21366 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-13 14:00:00+00 | 1.21699 | 1.2172 | 1.21345 | 1.21405 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-13 13:00:00+00 | 1.21887 | 1.2194 | 1.21629 | 1.21719 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-13 12:00:00+00 | 1.21848 | 1.22014 | 1.21747 | 1.21888 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-13 11:00:00+00 | 1.21676 | 1.21886 | 1.21601 | 1.21845 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-13 10:00:00+00 | 1.21912 | 1.21941 | 1.21675 | 1.21676 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-13 09:00:00+00 | 1.2214 | 1.22144 | 1.21873 | 1.21911 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-13 08:00:00+00 | 1.22113 | 1.22195 | 1.22072 | 1.22139 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-13 07:00:00+00 | 1.21875 | 1.22255 | 1.21869 | 1.22113 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-13 06:00:00+00 | 1.22054 | 1.22056 | 1.21852 | 1.21876 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-13 05:00:00+00 | 1.22032 | 1.2208 | 1.22021 | 1.22057 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-13 04:00:00+00 | 1.22036 | 1.22051 | 1.22006 | 1.22032 |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-13 03:00:00+00 | 1.22045 | 1.22082 | 1.22019 | 1.22036 |

Partial output from query:

| ticker | timestamp | open | high | low | close | pivot_low | pivot_high | timeframe |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-16 18:00:00+00 | 1.22147 | 1.2217 | 1.22102 | 1.2213 | t | f | 1h |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-16 10:00:00+00 | 1.21463 | 1.2157 | 1.21428 | 1.21517 | f | t | 1h |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-13 17:00:00+00 | 1.2137 | 1.21376 | 1.21225 | 1.21326 | f | t | 1h |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-13 07:00:00+00 | 1.21875 | 1.22255 | 1.21869 | 1.22113 | t | f | 1h |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-12 19:00:00+00 | 1.21734 | 1.21803 | 1.21719 | 1.21758 | f | t | 1h |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-12 06:00:00+00 | 1.23232 | 1.23317 | 1.23161 | 1.23236 | t | f | 1h |

**The Problem**

What I think the window function should be doing is going 1 row at a time and comparing 12 rows up and 9 rows down for if the current row is the highest value or lowest value. The output in the query seems to reflect how I want the data to appear except for the first entry for the high or low.

| ticker | timestamp | open | high | low | close | pivot_low | pivot_high | timeframe |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-16 18:00:00+00 | 1.22147 | 1.2217 | 1.22102 | 1.2213 | t | f | 1h |
| GBPUSD | 2023-10-16 10:00:00+00 | 1.21463 | 1.2157 | 1.21428 | 1.21517 | f | t | 1h |

Why are these entries showing up when it isn't possible for then to have 12 rows ahead to check and how can i fix it?

Comment: A fiddle (random example: https://dbfiddle.uk/j82cHZ8k) would make it so much easier for us to help. And always disclose your version of Postgres, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that nothing in the description of window functions says that a row is disqualified if the windows is shortened through lack of data.  Indeed that would seem like a pretty bad design decision to work like that. This is described in [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) as:

> In any case, the distance to the end of the frame is limited by the distance to the end of the partition, so that for rows near the partition ends the frame might contain fewer rows than elsewhere.

But you can count the data in the window frame and filter on that.

```
SELECT *
FROM  (SELECT *
        , high > max(high) OVER (PARTITION BY ticker ORDER BY _1h DESC ROWS BETWEEN 12 PRECEDING AND 9 FOLLOWING EXCLUDE CURRENT ROW) AS pivot_low,
          low < min(low) OVER (PARTITION BY ticker ORDER BY _1h DESC ROWS BETWEEN 12 PRECEDING AND 9 FOLLOWING EXCLUDE CURRENT ROW) AS pivot_high,
          '1h' AS timeframe,
          count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ticker ORDER BY _1h DESC ROWS BETWEEN 12 PRECEDING AND 9 FOLLOWING EXCLUDE CURRENT ROW) AS cnt
    FROM _1_hour
    ORDER BY _1h DESC
    ) sub
WHERE (pivot_high or pivot_low) 
      AND cnt=21
ORDER BY ticker, _1h DESC;
```

Comment: I've been getting better at fixing problems myself instead of needing to post and ask but I couldn't find anything that talked about the row disqualification. Is there some documentation you found the answer in? Thanks for pointing this out!